# Request to /shares Returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

My request to the shared file looks like this:

```
request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
response = request.GetResponse();
```

where the requestUri looks something like this:

```
https://api.dropbox.com/1/shares/auto/New%20Text%20Document.txt?
oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY&oauth_nonce=913151&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-
SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1428055275&oauth_token=TOKEN&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signatur
e=BLABLABLA
```

request.GetResponse() throws a WebException, which says:

> The remote server returned an error: *(401) Unauthorized*. And for
>   the detailed information I receive this: *Additional information: The
>   underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust
>   relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.*

The flow is like this: I upload the file with the same authorization parameters ***successfully*** and then I try to retrieve the newly uploaded file's shortened URL using the call shown above but receive the exception.

Please note that this worked some time ago. Probably they've changed something in the API, but I cannot find how to do it correctly. So, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please check your app key(consumer key) . looks like it was not provided correctly.

Comment: It's a sample key, not the real one. Please check the comments below

Answer (score 0):

When I put the address into my URL it states:

`{"error": "Invalid app key (consumer key). Check your app's configuration to make sure everything is correct."}`

Get a new app key and see if it then works.

Answer (score 0):

In your URL it shows oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY I don't think so oauth_consumer_Key will generate key in that way it is just for an example.

You have to login and need to follow proper steps as below to get your App key Below URL provide you all steps.

**Steps:**

- Login to Dropbox
- Click on the link “Developers” which is displayed on    the bottom
  (center) of the page
- Click on the link “My Apps” displayed in the
- menu on the left side     Now click on the button “Create an App”

For more detail [click here](http://cgeers.com/2011/12/29/dropbox-rest-api-part-1-authentication/)

Comment: MY_KEY is just for an example, it is not a real key. I've already created the App and have been using the API successfully for several months. Even this link for share URL worked fine. It started returning an error a couple of weeks ago. So I wonder what I'm doing wrong according to the new API standards

Answer (score 0):

I believe we solved this via a Dropbox support ticket. As far as I can tell, the issue was that a nonce was being reused.

Comment: Hi @smarx, actually the nonce wasn't the issue initially. I just tried to generate it only once later, hoping that this might solve my problem. So the original version didn't reuse it, but it still didn't work. Now, what really happened is that I reverted my changes and it started to work again (though the same code didn't work yesterday). So, I'm not sure what happened really. I'll just continue testing. Thanks